# Enable a generic user to start X

Tags: debian, permissions, xorg, display-manager

I have Debian, Sid if it matters, and I'd like to start X from the console, rather than using a display manager, but when i type `startx <RET>` I receive the following message

```
xinit: connection to X server lost
```

If I'm logged as root, or if I use `sudo`, I'm able to start X so I suspect that permissions are at the root of the problem .

What should I do to enable generic users to start X, possibly via `startx` ?

I'm interested both in a simple solution, achieved probably manipulating permissions, that has other drawbacks and in a possibly more complicated solution, maybe a proxy like a sort of *non-graphical display manager*, or whatever else…

Comment: Do you have just "regular" Debian Sid, or have you swapped things like the init system or custom ~/.xserverrc? I'm asking because unprivileged startx has, in fact, been working _by default, for many years_ on stock Debian & Arch installs; if I remember correctly it was possible all the way back in 2008 and is still possible now. (Though the actual mechanism by which it works has changed during the init system switchover.)

Comment: I have regular Debian Sid, and it's a long time (_almost_ forever)I have not been able to use `startx` but I had to rely on a display manager.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the .xauthority and .ICEauthority files are owned by root. Attempt to remove them, or, in order not to break something, move them away:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.bak.Xauthority
sudo mv ~/.ICEauthority ~/.bak.ICEauthority
```

It is recommended to perform this in a non-X environment, by switching to a virtual terminal using i.e. Ctrl + Alt + F2.

Comment: The files you mention are created  from the X server before any error is issued and their `user.group`  is correct (i.e., `boffi.boffi`). So no, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/start-x-as-a-user-other-than-root?rq=1) (*"Start X as a user other than root"*) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1929/164535), that references [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Rootless), I came up with the following solution

```
sudo chown $USER /dev/tty8
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/input/*
startx -- vt8 -retro -sharevts -logfile ~/.local/X.log &
```

The Xorg server is started *correctly (?)* but, all the possible security issues notwithstanding, a bunch of other issues follows, e.g.,

1. some stuff typed in Chrome's search box ends up in the console that launched `X` together with a little amount of garbage,
2. I'm unable to use the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> sequence to switch to another terminal
3. some clients that were provided automagically by the display manager are no longer present, most annoyingly the whatever it is that intercepts the uses of <kbd>Multi Key</kbd> and places the composed character on the bus(???), to be seen by Chrome that otherwise ignores X's compose sequences (very annoying, as I use a US kbd layout but I like to write, e.g., Barbora Krejčíková w/o copy&paste).

I'd like to hear, possibly in comments, about possible fixes to the aforementioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

This has been possible by default for many years. Something on your system has made it *no longer possible* and the real question isn't "what mechanism to use to make it work" but rather "how to make the existing mechanism work *again*".

There are two different mechanisms which allow unprivileged startx usage:

- Previously (pre-systemd), the X server `/usr/bin/Xorg` used to be setuid root. This was the traditional mechanism, especially when Xorg still used to do direct PCI access. Now Xorg itself is not setuid but comes with a setuid launcher "Xorg.wrap" which detects whether root rights should be retained or not.
- Now, the *systemd-logind* daemon automatically grants permissions to the user corresponding to the foreground tty. This partially predates systemd, as udev + ConsoleKit already used to add the "foreground" user to various /dev ACLs even before that; however, systemd-logind additionally acts as a proxy for Xorg to access /dev/input without directly having rights there.

  On distributions which don't use systemd, the *elogind* daemon can do the same. On distributions which would like to avoid systemd at all costs, the *seatd* daemon may be used (although with a different API which Xorg doesn't yet support, as far as I know).

As Debian primarily uses systemd, you should have systemd-logind running, and your PAM configuration should invoke pam_systemd.so to register console logins with the daemon. When you log in at the console, `loginctl session-status` should report you as the active user on "seat0", and `getfacl /dev/snd/pcm*` should list you as having r/w access to audio devices.

(Note: You *actually* have to log in as the correct user. Logging in as root and using `su -l <myuser>` *explicitly does not count* – if you only do this then the session remains owned by root; device access rights will not be transferred when 'su' is used.)

When everything works correctly, Xorg will be able to directly open the GPU through /dev/dri, and will talk to systemd-logind through D-Bus to open devices in /dev/input; you should see this mentioned in your Xorg.0.log. (This uses the *system* bus, not a session bus – i.e. dbus.service and not dbus-launch.)

Do note that with systemd-logind or elogind, you should be starting Xorg on the same foreground VT, directly on top of your text-based login – *not* on a dedicated VT. This means using `vt$(fgconsole)` and not `vt8` (though Debian's startx does the right thing by default).

In **some** situations (e.g. when using the proprietary nVidia GPU drivers without kernel modesetting support), systemd-logind's ACLs and proxying might not be enough and you'll still need to use a setuid Xorg. This can be enabled in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` as documented in *Xorg.wrap(1)*.

Comment: Your post is indeed _informative_, but is it _propositive_? I dare say no.

Comment: I propose that you go through the described mechanisms one by one and make sure that they work on your system as described, until you find one that doesn't, and fix it until it does.